# Symfony 5 form handle request is executing the same query twice

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

So I'm starting a new Symfony 5 application, and having some trouble in a editing controller, imho, symfony is executing a dumb query.

So, below is the code of my controller and where is executing duplicate query and the queries. If anyone could help me out, would be very thankfull, If more code is needed, please let me know.

The repeated query, just occurs when submiting the request, not getting it. So just in the POST method.

EDIT: So... I found out, something that is causing, in formtype `'by_reference'=> false`, but I want to use it. So I could solve it in a ugly way, doing:

```
$product = $this->productRepository->find($id);
$product->getImages()->initialize();
```

It looks like, if I pre load entity, it works fine, maybe because of something that by reference does, not take from entity cache, like the example in docs:

From symfony docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html

```
// If you set by_reference to false, submitting looks like this:
$article->setTitle('...');
$author = clone $article->getAuthor();
$author->setName('...');
$author->setEmail('...');
$article->setAuthor($author);
```

```
class ProductController extends AbstractController
{
    public function editProduct(Request $request, int $id)
    {
        // Here it executes the query for getting the product, its ok
        $product = $this->productRepository->find($id);

        // Here it executes the query of the images, for handling the forms
        $form = $this->createForm(ProductType::class, $product);

        // Here is the problem, it executes the same query AGAIN!
        $form->handleRequest($request);
    }
}
```

So, I don't know why when I call `$form->handleRequest()`, It executes a query, that already runned, bellow is some usefull code, that maybe I mess up.

```
Query runned twice:
SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.image AS image_2, t0.product_id AS product_id_3 FROM product_image t0 WHERE t0.product_id = ?
```

```
class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
            $builder
                ->add('images', CollectionType::class, [
                    'label'             => false,
                    'entry_type'        => ImageType::class,
                    'entry_options' => [
                        'label' => false,
                    ],
                    'prototype'         => true,
                    'allow_add'         => true,
                    'allow_delete'      => true,
                    'by_reference'      => false,
                    'required'          => false,
                    'attr' => ['class' => 'row text-center text-lg-left'],
                ]);

    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Product::class,
        ]);
    }
```

```
class: App\Entity\Catalog\Product
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ProductRepository::class)
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductImage", mappedBy="product", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $images;

    /**
     * @return ProductImage[]|ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getImages()
    {
        return $this->images;
    }

    /**
     * @param ProductImage $productImage
     * @return Product
     */
    public function addImage(ProductImage $productImage): self
    {
        $productImage->setProduct($this);
        $this->images->add($productImage);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param ProductImage $productImage
     * @return $this
     */
    public function removeImage(ProductImage $productImage): self
    {
        $productImage->setProduct(null);
        $this->images->removeElement($productImage);
        return $this;
    }

}
```

```
class: App\Entity\Catalog\ProductImage
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ProductImageRepository::class)
 */
class ProductImage
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="images")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $product;
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely sure that you don't have a redirect going on somewhere in your actual controller code?  Seems strange.  Off-topic but I'm pretty sure you don't want onDelete cascade in your product image.  That would imply that you want the the product to be deleted if the image is deleted.  Probably just want a cascade all in the product.

Comment: I'm sure, because I exited the code right away, so I know, thats the two methods that are calling the queries, maybe I messed up in some other file, that uses it, but IDK where. About the onDelete cascade, are you sure is not opposite? When the product is deleted, the images are deleted as well?

Comment: Consider creating a new project, copy paste just the two entities, controller and form into it along with a minimal template.  Nothing else.  See if the problem persists.  The profiler bar should list any queries for you.  If there is still a problem then check the new project into github and post a link.

Comment: Another option would be to just go ahead and add a findProductWith Images method to your product repository and join product and images in it.  The advantage is that you will only need one query to get both product and images.  Basically bypasses the lazy loading stuff.  Something you will probably want to do eventually anyways.  Still does not explain why you are getting two product image queries.

Comment: I will try to create a new project and reproduce the error, writing just basic things. Oh, btw, the two queries occurs, only when Im submiting the form, when getting, It runs just once, I will edit the question to be more clear.

How would you do it with just one query?! Eager load? Is that a good option? In my vision, maybe is bad for caching, I would have better control caching two sepates queries than one. And in the future, product would have many others relations, like categories, attributes etc.

Comment: When you write a [DQL query](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#locking-support) with an explicit leftJoin('product.images','images') in it, then the images will be eager loaded.  The problem with lazy loading is that number of querys can increase dramatically especially when dealing with multiple products.  Even with caching, performance can be noticeably impacted.  As a general rule, when you know that you need related entities then you should consider explicitly querying for them.

Comment: I really don't know much about it, but in my mind, if you have just one query with eager load, you will have a lot of problem, chaching and invalidating the cache of those entities,  but I could be wrong. I will give it a look.

I use a lot of Laravel, and the eager load of it, doesn`t do just one query, but one for relation, if you have multiple products, it would do a "select * from product_image where product_id in ({product ids})", something like that, and you hydrate the right models.

Comment: @Cerad Hey, I was trying to replicate the error and find out is the `'by_reference' => false` of the type, I don't know if I need this or not, I'm not home right now to test, but if I remove that, I doesn't execute the unnecessary query